# Fastest way to shift rows of matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, shift

I have a 4x4 matrix like this:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I want to shift each row left (left circular shift), by the amount of the row index. I.e. row 0 stays as is, row 1 shifts left 1, row 2 shifts left 2, etc.

So we get this:

```
1  2  3  4
6  7  8  5
11 12 9  10
16 13 14 15
```

The fastest way I've come up with to do this in Python is the following:

```py
import numpy as np
def ShiftRows(x):
    x[1:] = [np.append(x[i][i:], x[i][:i]) for i in range(1, 4)]
    return x
```

I need to run this function on thousands of 4x4 matrices like this, so speed is important (to the extent possible in Python). I'm not concerned about using other modules such as numpy, I'm only concerned with speed.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: what format do your 4x4 have atm? simply python lists? files on a disk? lists of lists? simple lists?

Comment: It's a numpy 2d array

Comment: always 4x4?  or just always square?

Comment: Always 4x4, not just square

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind hard-coding an array size, in my testing it's about 6x as fast to just hard-code the rearrangement pattern:

```
def rot(a):
    return a.take((0,1,2,3,5,6,7,4,10,11,8,9,15,12,13,14)).reshape(4, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

### First improvement, get rid of list comprehension

I assume that your input will always be a 4x4 ndarray. If not, you need to modify the functions appropriately (i.e. add `np.asarray`, check dimensions etc.) Removing the list comprehension gives a nice speedup already:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)

def ShiftRows(x):
    x[1:] = [np.append(x[i][i:], x[i][:i]) for i in range(1, 4)]
    return x

def shift(x):
    for i in range(1, 4):
        x[i] = np.append(x[i, i:], x[i, :i])
    return x

%timeit ShiftRows(a)
# 38.6 µs ± 1.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit shift(a)
# 31.9 µs ± 583 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Keep in mind that both variants modify the array in-place. If that is not what you want, add a `x = x.copy()` at the beginning of both functions.

From my testing `numpy.roll` is much slower than either version.

### Second improvement, use [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/)

Now, the real speedup comes when we use [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/):

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def shift_numba(x):
    for i in range(1, 4):
        x[i] = np.append(x[i, i:], x[i, :i])
    return x    

%timeit shift_numba(a)
# 2.5 µs ± 115 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

That is about a factor of 15 faster than what you have now. Using `parallel` mode does not increase the performance, probably because of the tiny size of the array.

---

### Test: Unrolling the loop

At request of Patrick Artner, I unrolled the loop (well possible with 4x4):

```
@numba.njit
def shift_numba_unrolled(x):
    x[1] = np.append(x[1, 1:], x[1, :1])
    x[2] = np.append(x[2, 2:], x[2, :2])
    x[3] = np.append(x[3, 3:], x[3, :3])
    return x

%timeit shift_numba_unrolled(a)
# 2.49 µs ± 85 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Unrolling seems to produce the same results.

---

EDIT: Fixed a big problem, speedup is much less now.

Comment: manuallly unrolling the loop for normal python is more performant - maybe check it for this approach as well?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I will show the results in a minute.

Comment: these are great solutions.  Just a note that numba/jit very much depends on your hardware.  I get less than 10x improvement for the numba solutions

Comment: EDIT: I found an error in my code, and added the correct numbers. The unrolled one has the same performance as the non-unrolled one.

Answer (score 0):

Base solution using just list of lists (for those that find this question without numpy in mind):

```
import numpy as np

def SimpleShift(x):
    for i in range(1,4):
        # inplace slicing
        x[i][:] = x[i][i:] + x[i][:i]
    return x

def EvenSimplerShift(x):
    # manually unrolled loop
    x[1][:] = x[1][1:] + x[1][:1]
    x[2][:] = x[2][2:] + x[2][:2]
    x[3][:] = x[3][3:] + x[3][:3]
    return x

from timeit import timeit

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

print(data)
print(SimpleShift(data))
print(EvenSimplerShift(data))

print(timeit(lambda:SimpleShift(data)))
print(timeit(lambda: EvenSimplerShift(data)))
```

to get

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 5], [11, 12, 9, 10], [16, 13, 14, 15]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 5], [11, 12, 9, 10], [16, 13, 14, 15]]

4.8055571                 # timing with for loop
4.098531100000001         # timing with unrolled loop
```

so manually unrolling the loop seems to be faster. you might want to take a look at that using numpy as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import numpy as np


def stepped_roll(arr):
    return np.array([np.roll(row, -n) for n, row in enumerate(arr)])


print(stepped_roll(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]])))
```

I'd favour using `np.roll` because the numpy routines tend to be faster than what you can do in Python. `np.apply_along_axis` doesn't work here sadly, because you need the index of each row as you go.

In your case though, the operation is so trivial and the data set so small, something like the `shift()` function suggested in @JanChristophTerasa's answer will be much faster.